# What parts to control a 220V button (not constant, but connecting for 1 second)?

Tags: switches

I want to automate a dumb analogue door opener. My guess is that if I connect the two lines for a short amount of time (1 second, maybe), the motor on the door opener works to open the door. The dangerous point is that the door opener seems to be using 220 volts, so probably 220 volts are passing through the two lines.

PS: The answer seems to be a "relay".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have to ask you obviously do not have the expertise.

Mains power is dangerous and it is illegal in most jurisdictions for an unlicensed person to install wiring.

Comment: @DamnVegetables - the fact that you just said "if it is dangerous" confirms that you should not be tinkering with such things. It's not a case of "if" ... it IS dangerous (deadly)